# Set default tint color for all UIButtons in an app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

My iPad app I has a number of UIButtons that when pressed turn blue by default. I could go through each one and set the tintcolor using:

```
[buttonName setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:151/255.0f green:202/255.0f blue:86/255.0f alpha:1.0]];
```

But is there anyway of changing this colour by default and for all buttons?

Is there anyway of changing this colour?

Comment: Look at the [UIAppearance Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thanks - this looks perfect. Do I change the UIAppearance.h file? Or do I put the line for default tint color somewhere else?

Comment: Even tough the UIAppearance is the preferred choice, I found out that by switching the project to iOS 7 the appearance change a lot, and look totally different than it was designed. So besides that I would give also a try to subclassing as suggested, I also recommend to test the app with iOS 7 if you choose UIAppearance. Also, if you change appearance, you change for all buttons in the app, there's no way to apply to a restricted set.

Comment: @RichardGriffiths Of course you do not change the header of the protocol, which should be anyway locked for editing. See [this tutorial here](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/08/24/using-appearance-proxy-to-style-apps.html), which seems to be well writen

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the UIAppearance Protocol:

```
 [[UIButton appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:151/255.0f green:202/255.0f blue:86/255.0f alpha:1.0]];
```

Comment: Thanks. As my comment above - do I change the appearance.h? I have looked at that but it says it is locked.

Comment: no you don't have to change any headers files, just put this line in AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

Comment: You don't (and can't) edit Appearance.h directly as it's part of the iOS SDK. You would need to add the code suggested by peko to one of your files. Probably in a class that would be used to style the app in such a way.

Comment: I really appreciate everyone's help. So my question is now where do I put it? In AppDelegate.m?

Comment: yes, there should be a method called application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:, put it there

Answer (score 26):

If you are using storyboards and Xcode 5.0 or later, the easiest way to do this is to open up your storyboard in Xcode and set the Global Tint color setting in the File Inspector in the Utility area.  See illustration below.

[image: Setting the Global Tint in the File Inspector]

Comment: How to do this on Xcode 12, it's not showing Global tint?

Answer (score 1):

You could subclass uibutton and set the color to whatever you want there. Then any button with that class will have the same color

Comment: Subclassing for changing only a color is not a good idea in general.