# Is it possible to override the style of all UIButtons text

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

We are using a 3rd party SDK that creates popup UIViews (think social signon stuff). The button text is iOS7 blue, but we need to override them.

Wondering if I am going to have to monkey patch the SDK or if I can override on some other level?

Comment: i think you are looking for uibutton appearance.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18615231/set-default-tint-color-for-all-uibuttons-in-an-app

Answer (score 0):

Place following

```
[[UIButton appearance] setTitleColor:[UIColor purpleColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

in

```
- ( BOOL ) application:( UIApplication* ) application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:( NSDictionary* ) launchOptions
```

and you will change color of all buttons in application.

To change more selective read first this article http://nshipster.com/uiappearance/

Comment: Already doing this button appearance in iOS7 isn't reaching down that far into this SDK for some reason. When the popup is shown it ignores this appearance settings.